# server hangs randomly without log entries

Tags: linux, troubleshooting, io

My physical server hangs randomly and I do not get any log entries during that time. So I let a script run:

```
while true; do date >>/tmp/dates; sleep 1; done & disown
```

After some minutes the file /tmp/dates has "holes". Sometimes the dates are interrupted for 30 seconds, sometimes for 3 minutes in a row:

```
Thu Feb 13 14:54:39 CET 2014
Thu Feb 13 14:54:40 CET 2014
Thu Feb 13 14:57:45 CET 2014
Thu Feb 13 14:57:46 CET 2014
```

The server does not show high load or memory utilization. /var/log/messages does not show anything for the times when the server hangs. However it does have some messages about IO problems like a fibrechannel link taking a nap. I am booting from SAN, so / is on a multimapper device. If I call

```
while true; do date >>/tmp/dates; sleep 1; done & disown
while true; do date >>/dev/shm/dates; sleep 1; done & disown
```

There will be no holes in /dev/shm/dates, but there will be holes in /tmp/dates so I think it is not a kernel hang situation, but an IO hang situation.

I can see no processes in uninterruptible sleep state in top. No entries in the hardware or storage log that seem relevant.

However iostat shows high latency spikes regarding await:

```
03/28/14 12:32:00
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
dm-4              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00   214.00    0.00   0.00 100.00

03/28/14 12:32:01
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
dm-4              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00   214.00    0.00   0.00 100.00

03/28/14 12:32:02
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
dm-4              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00   214.00    0.00   0.00 100.00

03/28/14 12:32:03
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
dm-4              0.00     0.00    0.00 1219.00     0.00     4.76     8.00    45.61 5251.48   0.82 100.40

03/28/14 12:32:04
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
dm-4              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     2.99    0.00   0.00  99.60

03/28/14 12:32:05
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
dm-4              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     3.01    0.00   0.00 100.40

03/28/14 12:32:06
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
dm-4              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     3.00    0.00   0.00 100.00
```

Could it be that the kernel is waiting for IO from the storage and does not do anything until the block arrives? What else could it be? How can I find out?

Comment: What is your load and how many CPUs do you have?

Comment: CPU load is less than 10%, 80 logical CPUs

Comment: Load is a value, not a percentage.

Comment: load is below 0.1

Comment: Is this a real host or a virtual machine?

Comment: Do you have steal time in top? Which kernel version do you use? Do you use plain Linux kernel or sg. like Xen modified kernel?

Comment: real, non-virtualized host. I got a problem the same problem in a VM so I decided to do a bare-metal installation.

Comment: Linux vcehanar15 3.0.101-0.7.15-default #1 SMP Wed Jan 15 22:13:35 UTC 2014 (0e621ee) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: I don't understand why the answer to this isn't install monitoring and gather evidence. Everything else is just guessing.

Comment: which monitoring do you recommend?

Comment: Echo not just time but iostat, top, vmstat and few others to shm and see what is happening during the hangs.

Comment: Yeah, this is a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the FC-switch's error log we found one port with a huge error log. We disabled this port and have not seen the error for a whole weekend now. So I think this error has been caused by a broken fibrechannel path. Usually, to my information, such an error should be detected (e.g. by multipathd), logged and auto-corrected. So I assume we have one of the cases of an undetected fibrechannel path fault here.